# Index copied into Excel misreads 'fi' combination

Tags: pdftex, excel

Using R and its `knitr` package under Windows 10 to produce a PDF file with an index, I have found that indexed words with 'fi' in them often appear incorrectly when I copy the index into Excel [to do other work with it there].  For example, condence intervals or entropy based lter.

Is there a package or technique that will correct this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Without MWE difficult to say, but what about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{}
\begin{document}
 Auflaufform
\end{document}
```

No ligatures (ahem, not tested).

(Example stolen here: http://texwelt.de/wissen/antwort_link/57/ )

Comment: I get this error in the log file: Disabling ligatures of a font is only possible
(microtype)                with pdftex version 1.30 or newer.
(microtype)                Ignoring \DisableLigatures.

Comment: Well, then please update your installation of texlive or miktex.